How to redirect URL containing question mark and a specific string to the root domain with .htaccess
The old url structure of my website was something like this
https://www.naturablooms.com/wholesale-pricelist?color_id&flower_type_id&name_search_start&page=1&product_type=Dried&psearch&ship_service

Our website current url structure changed for SEO. Now we have to redirect all this kind of url which has color_id after the question mark to root domain. Which is like
from
https://www.naturablooms.com/wholesale-pricelist?color_id&flower_type_id&name_search_start&page=1&product_type=Dried&psearch&ship_service

to
https://www.naturablooms.com/

We tried the following in the .htaccess
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^color_id.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [R=301,L]

but it will redirect to
https://www.naturablooms.com/wholesale-pricelist
not the root domain
https://www.naturablooms.com/
We need to redirect it to https://www.naturablooms.com/
I will really appreciate if someone help me to figure and resolve this.

This probably is what you are looking for:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^color_id&
RewriteRule ^ / [R=301,L,QSD]

Or maybe that, this is not really clear from your question:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^color_id&
RewriteRule ^/?wholesale-pricelist/?$ / [R=301,L,QSD]

Your previous rule explicitly copied the requested path, since you were using the placeholder $1 which contains whatever is captured by the matching pattern. You neither need to capture anything, nor do you need to copy anything.

Perfect, thank you so much

@AyanBiswas Glad I could help. Did you understand why your approach did not work? What the actual difference is? It is important that you do not just copy something, but that you learn how to solve such issues yourself. Do yourself the favor to invest a bit of effort into that. It is well worth it.
